# Is there a class of optimization problems more general than semidefinite programming?

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization

I was TA-ing my convex optimization class and explaining that [linear programs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) are a special case of [second-order cone programs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_cone_programming), which are themselves special cases of [semidefinite programs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidefinite_programming). Is there any well-established class of optimization problems that is more general than semidefinite programs? *Conic optimization* problems would be an example of this, but I'm hoping for something a little more algebraic, if it exists.

Answer (score 15):

There is the concept of *hyperbolic programming*, introduced in the 90's by Osman Güler:

- O. Güler, *Hyperbolic Polynomials and Interior Point Methods for Convex Programming*, Math. Oper. Res. **22** (1997) 350-377.

See also

- H.H. Bauschke, O. Güler, A.S. Lewis, H.S. Sendov, *Hyperbolic Polynomials and Convex Analysis*, Canad. J. Math. **53** (2001) 470-488;
- J. Renegar, *Hyperbolic Programs, and their Derivative Relaxations*, Found. Comput. Math. **6** (2005) 59–79.

It is based on the concept of *hyperbolicity cone* introduced by Lars Gårding in the 50's in the context of the theory of hyperbolic partial differential equations.

We say that an homogeneous polynomial $P:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is *hyperbolic* with respect to $\tau\in\mathbb{R}^n$ if $P(\tau)\neq 0$ and the roots of the one-variable polynomial $P_{\xi,\tau}(\lambda)\doteq P(\xi-\lambda\tau)$ are all *real* for all $\xi\in\mathbb{R}^n$. We then define the *hyperbolicity cone* $C(P,\tau)$ of $P$ with respect to $\tau$ as 
$$
C(P,\tau)=\{\xi\in\mathbb{R}^n\ |\ \text{the roots of }P_{\xi,\tau}\text{ are all positive}\}\ .
$$
It was shown by Gårding that $C(P,\tau)$ is an open, convex cone which is the connected component of $\{\xi\ |\ P(\xi)\neq 0\}$ to which $\tau$ belongs. Moreover, the closure of $C(P,\tau)$ has the form 
$$
\overline{C(P,\tau)}=\{\xi\in\mathbb{R}^n\ |\ \text{the roots of }P_{\xi,\tau}\text{ are all nonnegative}\}\ .
$$ 
Hyperbolic programming is then simply conic programming when the feasibility cone is (the closure of) an hyperbolicity cone of some hyperbolic polynomial $P$. Checking if $\xi\in\mathbb{R}^n$ belongs to $C(P,\tau)$ (resp. $\overline{C(P,\tau)}$) amounts to checking if the coefficients of the monic one-variable polynomial $P(\tau)^{-1}P_{\xi,\tau}=P_{\tau,\tau}(0)^{-1}P_{\xi,\tau}$ are all positive (resp. nonnegative).

Hyperbolic programming generalizes semidefinite programming in the following sense: if $\gamma_1,\ldots,\gamma_n$ are $N\times N$ symmetric matrices and we set $\gamma(\xi)=\sum^n_{j=1}\xi_j\gamma_j$, $\xi\in\mathbb{R}^n$, then $P(\xi)=\det\gamma(\xi)$ is an hyperbolic polynomial with respect to any $\tau\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\gamma(\tau)$ is positive definite. In that case, 
$$
C(P,\tau)=\{\xi\in\mathbb{R}^n\ |\ \gamma(\xi)\text{ is positive definite}\}
$$ 
and 
$$
\overline{C(P,\tau)}=\{\xi\in\mathbb{R}^n\ |\ \gamma(\xi)\text{ is positive semidefinite}\}\ .
$$ 
It is not known whether this is a *strict* generalization of semidefinite programming, though - it is in fact conjectured that any hyperbolicity cone can be represented as a cone of positive definite matrices for a suitable choice of $N$. Since this was originally conjectured (in a stronger form) by Peter Lax in the 50's for $n=3$, this (still open) conjecture became known as the *generalized Lax conjecture*. Lax's original claim was proven by A.S. Lewis, P.A. Parrilo and M.V. Ramana (*The Lax Conjecture is True*, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. **133** (2005) 2495-2499) building on work by J.W. Helton and V. Vinnikov (*Linear Matrix Inequality Representation of Sets*, Commun. Pure Appl. Math. **60** (2007) 654-674).

Comment: It appears that the question has been resolved. In the 2023 pre-print titled "[Sums of Squares Representations on Singular Loci](https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.05081)", authored by Ngoc Hoang Anh Mai and Victor Magron, it is claimed that every hyperbolic program is equivalent to a semidefinite program.

Comment: Thanks for the link. The preprint is quite fresh (it was posted on the arXiv last Thursday, March 9th), so it'd perhaps be wise to wait a bit until the claim is validated, no errors are found, etc..

Comment: Either way, the authors do *not* actually claim they've solved the generalized Lax conjecture. To quote from Remark 14 on page 24 (see also earlier, on page 4), "it has yet to easily be seen that the result of Corollary 2 provides a solution to the generalized Lax conjecture. It is because the equivalence of hyperbolic and semidefinite programs might not directly imply the equality of their feasible sets." (Corollary 2, pp. 23 from Section 7 is the stated equivalence between hyperbolic programs and semidefinite programs)

Comment: Regardless of the ensuing status of the generalized Lax conjecture, if correct the claim indeed settles the case whether both kinds of programming are equivalent or not (apparently, they should be).

Comment: Thank you for bringing up these important points. Indeed, I was originally referring to the question of equivalence between hyperbolic and semidefinite programs, but didn't notice that my comment was ambiguous.

Answer (score 6):

If you like, you might look at cones of sums of squares of polynomials (cones of PSD matrices are the same thing as cones of sums of squares of linear polynomials). This is the starting point of the modern technique of solving optimisation problems on semi-algebraic sets, due to J.Lasserre and others.

More generally, you might look at cones of nonnegative polynomials, and this opens up the whole Hilbert 17th problem business.

Comment: But you can rewrite these sum of squares cones as projections of appropriate linear sections of larger positive semidefinite cones, so from a strict representability perspective you don't get anything new here.

Comment: this is only true asymptotically --- and then, you know, every nice function on a compact  is asymptotically a polynomial, so why bother :-)

Comment: OK, it's not quite true what I just wrote. I meant cones of nonnegative polynomials.

Comment: Ok, well cones of nonnegative polynomials are more general than SDP cones, but unfortunately computationally intractable.

Comment: well, it what sense are they intractable? E.g. if you fix the number of variables, things are not as bad (e.g. for 2 variables things can be done in polynomial time, as we showed long time ago; http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.ejor.2003.08.014)

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't realized the two-variable case was tractable.  I was referring to e.g. the fact that for the degree four case with $n$ variables, checking membership in the cone of nonnegative polynomials is NP-hard.

Comment: speaking about complexity, for SDPs in general is it not known, and so one has to tread carefully here.