# Advantages of hyperbolic programming over semidefinite programming?

Tags: convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming

What are the advantages of a hyperbolic program over a semi definite program?  SDPs can be used to represent a wide variety of algebraic constraints. Are there constraints that can be represented in a hyperbolic program but not a semi definite program?

Is there a reference that describes an application or applications of hyperbolic programming?

Has anyone developed a hyperbolic programming solver? If so, is there a reference describing its implementation?

Comment: Can you pose a more focused question? It looks at the moment like you want someone to write a wikipedia entry on the topic for you. Which can be answered by a simple google search...

Comment: I’ve done many google searches over the past few days. But still have not been able to confirm if someone has written a hyperbolic programming solver, or if there is an application of hyperbolic programming. I’ve also seen mention of a conjecture that hyperbolic programs might be SDP representable. I was hoping an expert in this area might be able to clear up some confusion. Pointing me to several references would also be helpful. No Wikipedia entry needed

Comment: Can you edit your question to make it more focused on these topic? It would attract more interest then...

Comment: cannot locate it right now, but I think a version of this question was asked on MO a few years ago and it received some good answers (except for the "solvers" part)

Comment: I guess Suvrit is talking about this answer: https://mathoverflow.net/a/231856/22389

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I'm not an expert in the area, just a fellow curious.*

Update (2023):  In the pre-print "[Sums of Squares Representations on Singular Loci](https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.05081)" by Ngoc Hoang Anh Mai and Victor Magron is claimed that every hyperbolic program is equivalent to a semidefinite program.

---

- As far I known, it is still unknown if hyperbolic feasibility problems are polynomial-time equivalent to LMI problems (1).
- Moreover (as of October 2018), it is also still unknown if every hyperbolic program might be recast as a semidefinite program, possibly involving more variables (2).
- Finally, an algorithm for solving hyperbolic programs is proposed in (3), but I don't know if an implementation is available. You may try to contact the author of the paper.

(1) *Tunçel, Levent*, Polyhedral and semidefinite programming methods in combinatorial optimization, Fields Institute Monographs 26. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS); Toronto: The Fields Institute for Research in Mathematical Sciences (ISBN 978-0-8218-3352-0/hbk). x, 219 p. (2010). [ZBL1207.90005](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1207.90005).

(2) *Saunderson, James*, [**A spectrahedral representation of the first derivative relaxation of the positive semidefinite cone**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s11590-018-1246-x), Optimization Letters. 12, No. 7, 1475-1486 (2018).

(3) *Renegar, James*, [**Accelerated first-order methods for hyperbolic programming**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10107-017-1203-y), Math. Program., Ser. A (2017).

Comment: I've listened a talk of Saunderson recently where he was commenting Levent Tuncel and/or his current PhD students might be the only people on the globe with a running hyperbolic programing solver in their laptops :)

Comment: @alpx Hope they open source it soon :)